# How to see if the object was fetched from cache in Firefox web-inspector?

Tags: firefox, web-inspector

When viewing Network tab of Firefox's dev tools, it does not show an entry for the file if it was fetched from the cache. Is there a way to find which files were picked from the cache?

Chrome's dev tools present this information. On the Network tab, in the size column it shows (from cache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug open on Firefox for the same thing.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764958

So there isn't a way, at least as of now, to know if the content was fetched from cache.

Comment: The bug has been fixed now and the 'Transferred' column in the network tab shows 'cached' for objects fetched from local storage.